# Аватары в комментариях

Tags: php, mysql

Есть, например, вывод комментов из mysql:

```
function get_comments() {
 for(...) {
  $id_author = $uinfo[$i][3]; // id автора, оставившегося комментарий
  $text_comment = $uinfo[$i][2]; // текст комментария
  echo "<тут например отобразить аватар юзера> $text_comment";
 }
}
```

Так вот, хотелось узнать, нужно писать сначала функцию для получения аватара определённого юзера, а потом вместо **<тут например отобразить аватар юзера>** подставлять функцию вида: `user_ava($id_author)`. Верно ли это или нет? Если нет, то какой способ будет правильным?

Comment: да, ничего плохого не вижу в этом.

Comment: так ведь запросов не много ли? А если ещё и имя с фамилией выводить например..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в цикле разбираете массив с данными: $id_author, $text_comment. 
В этот массив вам нужно добавить информацию о аватарке и извлекать её аналогично:
    $ava = $uinfo[$i][4]
Для этого, скорее всего, из БД нужно будет извлеч ёще одно поле, в котором хранится инфомрация о аватарке, а далее добавить его в массив. Не видя кода и структуры БД что-то более конкретное посоветовать сложно.

Comment: Вы походу не поняли. Мне не нужно заносить аватарку в отдельное поле, а нужно получать текущую, чтобы если её изменили, она изменённой отображалась в комментарии.